# Get only the count and link of PagedList not the data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, pagedlist

I want to show the number of pages in a post before showing it,

Link of post
and the count of pages of comments with links 1-2-3

I use nuget PagedList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
<h3>Page Numbers Only</h3>
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfProducts, 
    page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }), 
            PagedListRenderOptions.PageNumbersOnly)
```